# Output of first iteration as the input of the next step in a for loop

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, network-analyst, nameerror, closest-facility

I use a Python script to find the closest facilities. I have 24 cities to process. For one city, I should create 100 random datasets. To do that, I use Python, and `for` loops. After I create the random datasets, I need to find the closest facilities (schools) to random points (incidents)
This is the Python code I use, and it is not working. Why isn't it working?

```py
# Local variables:
Default_gdb = "C:\\Users\\Madusha\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb"
ms_gdb = "D:\\Crimems.gdb"
constrain = r"D:\Crime\ms.gdb\constrain"
Chicago_schools = r"C:\crime\ms.gdb\Chicago_schools"
Road_ND = r"D:\Crime\ms.gdb\Road_ND.nd"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = "True"
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

for n in range(1, 100):
    print 'Processing {0} of 100'.format(n)
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(ms_gdb, 'dataset_{}'.format(n) , constrain, constrain, "boundary", "constrain", "POINT", "0")
    arcpy.na.FindClosestFacilities(dataset.format(n), Chicago_schools, "Meters", Road_ND, ms_gdb,
                                   'Routes_{}'.format(n), 'Directions_{}'.format(n),
                                   'ClosestFacilities_{}'.format(n), "5", "2000")
```

This is the error message I got.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Crime\PythinCode\combine.py", line 30, in <module>
    arcpy.na.FindClosestFacilities(dataset.format(n), Chicago_schools, "Meters", Road_ND, ms_gdb,
NameError: name 'dataset' is not defined
```

Comment: If in doubt, you can always convert the execution statements into `print` statements. This could have helped diagnose what I have to guess is your issue (since you didn't define "not working") -- the "`dataset.format(n)`" in `FindClosestFacilities` should be `"dataset_{}".format(n)`

Comment: You could also use ListFeatureClasses